# c# MACTripleDES in ruby

Tags: c#, php, ruby, encryption

I have some data that is encrypted using MACTripleDES in c#, and I need to replicate the same encryption and possibly decryption in ruby. I see there is way in php to do this. [see this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10533604/mactripledes-in-php), I wonder if there any way I can do the same in ruby. So far I have tried all the des ciphers in openssl, but the results are not matching up. Below is my code snippet in ruby.

```
['des','des-cbc',
'des-cfb', 'des-ecb', 'des-ede', 'des-ede-cbc', 'des-ede-cfb',
'des-ede-ofb'  ,  'des-ede3'     ,  'des-ede3-cbc'  , 'des-ede3-cfb'  , 'des-ede3-ofb','des-ofb'   ,     'des3'    ,       'desx'  ].each do |alg|
    des = OpenSSL::Cipher::Cipher.new(alg)
    des.encrypt
    des.padding = 1
    des.key = secret_key
    update_value = des.update(data)
    up_final = update_value + des.final
    puts up_final
    puts Base64.encode64(up_final).gsub(/\n/, "")
end
```

And here is c# code snippet,

```
System.Security.Cryptography.MACTripleDES mac3des = new System.Security.Cryptography.MACTripleDES();
mac3des.Key = my_secret_key; 
mac3des.ComputeHash(System.Text.Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes(value));
```

Comment: Hashing isn't encryption.

Comment: Can you provide a set of matching results that were generated using the `C#` code?